# Client-Server communication in Java

Tags: java, server, client-server

I'm trying to create a client-server Java application, in which 4 users are connected, however I have some issues with the communication and message exchange between the Server and Client classes.

Here is the code for the Server:

```
public class Server {
    private static final int port = 9991;
    private static final String serverHost = "localhost";
    private static ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private static Socket socket;
    private static DataInputStream serverInput;
    private static DataOutputStream serverOutput;
    private static String message;
    private static int noOfUsers = 0;

    public static void main(String args[]){
        try{
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            System.out.println("Server is up (Port: " + port + ")");

            while (true){
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                serverInput = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                serverOutput = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

                message = serverInput.readUTF();
                if (message.equals("C_Message1")){
                    System.out.println("Client has connected!");
                    serverOutput.writeUTF("S_Message1");
                } 
                else if (message.equals("C_Message2")){
                    if (noOfUsers <= 3){
                        serverOutput.writeUTF("S_Message2");
                        noOfUsers++;
                    } 
                    else {
                        serverOutput.writeUTF("S_Message3");
                        System.out.println("User rejected");              
                    } 
                }

            } 
        } catch (IOException e){
            System.err.println(e.getMessage() + " -> " + e.getCause());
        }

    }
}
```

and here is the code for Client class:

```
public class Client implements Runnable {
    private static final int serverPort = 9991;
    private static final String serverHost = "localhost";

    private static Socket socket;
    private static DataInputStream clientInput;
    private static DataOutputStream clientOutput;

    private static String message;

    private static int userID;

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            socket = new Socket(serverHost, serverPort);
            System.out.println("Connection succesfull.");

            clientInput = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            clientOutput = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

            clientOutput.writeUTF("C_Message1");
            System.out.println("Connected to server!");

            while (true){
               message = clientInput.readUTF();

               if (message.equals("S_Message1")){
                   clientOutput.writeUTF("C_Message2");
               }
               else if (message.equals("S_Message2")){
                   System.out.println("Accepted on table!");
               } 
               else if (message.equals("S_Message3")){
                   System.out.println("Rejected");
               }   
            }                  
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.out.println("Cannot find host.");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IO Exception thrown");

        } 
    } 
}
```

and I'm creating an instance of Client inside my GUI class,

```
Client client = new Client();
Thread clientThread = new Thread(client);
clientThread.start();
```

The problem is that the message exchange does not work properly. 
I'm sending C_Message1 from Client to Server, when server receives this message, it sends back S_Message1 to client, and then the Client sends C_Message2 to Server and so on. 
However the message exchange, somehow stops when the client is trying to send C_Message2.

Comment: Your `accept` is inside the `while` loop. This means that after the new message, the server is accepting a new connection, the old socket is abandoned, and it will never receive any messages from it anymore.

Comment: Even if just a single user is connected to the server, the problem still exists. Moreover I can't see any other place where the `socket.accept()` can be placed. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: If you have just one user then it will just wait at the `socket.accept()` until a user connects... You should have a separate loop for accepting, and a separate loop for handling a single session - preferably in another thread (or you won't be able to accept another user).

Answer (score 1):

In a client server system like this one you have to handle two threads (at least) on client and two threads on server:

- one thread send messages
- one thread receive messages

It is an asynchronous that works basically as follow:

- Sender thread on client send a message "Hello"
- Receiver thread on server receive the message "Hello"
- Receiver thread create a new message "I received hello message" and put it on a shared list between receiver and sender thread of the server
- Sender thread of the server see that a new message is present on the shared list
- Sender thread extract the message from the list and sent it to client
- Receiver thread on the client receive a message "I received hello message"

I hope the process is clear. Good luck

Comment: Thanks fro your reply Davide. I'm a bit confused with the term 'shared list'. Any code-examples (not necessarily based on my code) are welcome.

Comment: Shared between threads. It means that you have to access it in a synchronized block otherwise you can have corrupt data reading it